# Title rendering issue

Tags: primefaces

I've implemented a `p:commandButton` to update the contents of a table when it is clicked. I think this is working (although It isn't properly tested) but the more immediate issue is as follows.

**Bug**

Before the request, the title bar looks like this:

[image]

And after I hit the refresh button on the right, the page re-renders as follows:

[image]

**Attempts to solve**

The following is the current code for my `p:commandButton`:

```
  <p>
      <p:commandButton oncomplete="eventFeedsDialog.show()" update=":eventFeedsForm" id="feedsRefresh" icon="ui-icon-refresh" title="Refresh page" style="height:40px; width:40px; float:right;">
             <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}" target="#{searchBean.refresh}"/>
      </p:commandButton>
  </p>
```

The `eventFeedsDialog` is the `p:dialog` element that this button is wrapped in, which is further wrapped in a `h:form` element. Here is the declaration of the `eventFeedsDialog` element:

```
<p:dialog id="eventFeedsDialog" header="Feeds" widgetVar="eventFeedsDialog" resizable="false" width="1000"
          styleClass="dialog">
```

I've tried changing the `oncomplete` attribute to point at the `h:form` instead of the `dialog`, but it appears not to have worked. I thought up a hack, whereby I append a mountain of spaces in the `header` attribute, but that is horrendously ugly.

I've not found anything on google like this, so I was wondering if you guys have any ideas?

Comment: since there is no much code provided, try to add a wrapper `<h:panelGroup` that will wrap the table and point to it in your `update` attribute of the `<p:commandButton`

Comment: I didn't provide a large amount of code because I figured this might be a common issue. Alas, it doesn't seem like it is!